# Detect authentication prompt (or pre-empt and avoid)

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, browser

Can you detect and prevent a browser authentication prompt with some JavaScript?

I'm building a little JavaScript snippet to demonstrate port-scanning for an ethical hacking workshop. I'm generating image tags in JavaScript to check the open/closed state of ports. When attempting to connect to an FTP server that requires authentication, the browser prompts for creds:

[image]

This prompt blocks the execution of the JavaScript (in fact pretty much blocks all browser activities - you can't switch tabs). Is there a way to detect when an authentication prompt is about to happen and somehow avoid it?

The port-scanning code is below (adapted from the [BeEF project](http://beefproject.com/)'s `port_scanner` module)

```
function check_port(host, port) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const start = (new Date).getTime()

        let img_scan = new Image()
        img_scan.src = 'ftp://' + host + ":" + port
        img_scan.onerror = function () {
            var delta = (new Date).getTime() - start;

            if (delta < closetimeout) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                resolve(false)
            }
        }
        img_scan.onload = img_scan.onerror

        interval = setInterval(function () {
            var delta = (new Date).getTime() - start

            if (delta >= opentimeout) {
                if (!img_scan) return
                img_scan = undefined
                clearInterval(interval)
                resolve(true)
            }
        }, 1)
    })
}

async function main() {
    let state = await check_port('192.168.1.1', 21)
    console.log(state)
}

main()
```

Comment: Just a side note, this line of code is a no-op: `img_scan.onload = img_scan.onerror`. `img_scan` is a brand-new image that hasn't had anything assigned to either `onload` or `onerror`, so they'll both have their initial default value of `null`. (Whereas if you move that line to after the line assigning to `onerror`, or combine them into `img_scan.onload = img_scan.onerror = function`, they'd both refer to the same function.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, amended

Comment: No, that is not possible. This is way outside of the realm that your script code embedded into a website is working in. At most you could perhaps check upfront by making the actual request somewhere else, and checking what response you get. (Using AJAX directly from the page won’t work - for one thing, that still pops up the dialog once a resource that does require authentication is encountered; plus for images from just any arbitrary source(?) the lack of CORS will probably stop you dead in your tracks already.)

Comment: It's an interesting one. Perhaps you could try to override the `window.prompt` method if it's the one used. So at the beginning of the javascript execution you could try something like: `window.prompt = function() {};`.
Let me know if somehow this input will achieve the goal please

Comment: @quirimmo this isn’t a prompt, it is not related to JavaScript at all. This is a feature build in to the browser UI; there is no scripting access to it whatsoever.

Comment: @quirimmo nope, doesn't work but was worth a shot. the `window.prompt` seems completeley unrelated to the authentication prompt (it doesn't block tab switching for one)

Comment: Use a server as a proxy :)